# Close connection with client after inactivty period

Tags: c++, sockets, epoll

I'm currently managing a server that can serve at most MAX_CLIENTS clients concurrently.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
//create and bind listen_socket_

struct pollfd poll_fds_[MAX_CLIENTS];

for (auto& poll_fd: poll_fds_)
{
    poll_fd.fd = -1;
}

listen(listen_socket_, MAX_CLIENTS);

poll_fds_[0].fd = listen_socket_;
poll_fds_[0].events = POLLIN;

while (enabled)
    {
        const int result = poll(poll_fds_, MAX_CLIENTS, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (result < 0)
        {
            // throw error
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto& poll_fd: poll_fds_)
            {
                if (poll_fd.revents == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (poll_fd.revents != POLLIN)
                {
                    // throw error
                }
                else if (poll_fd.fd == listen_socket_)
                {
                    int new_socket = accept(listen_socket_, nullptr, nullptr);

                    if (new_socket < 0)
                    {
                        // throw error
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        for (auto& poll_fd: poll_fds_)
                        {
                            if (poll_fd.fd == -1)
                            {
                                poll_fd.fd = new_socket;
                                poll_fd.events = POLLIN;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // serve connection
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything is working great, and when a client closes the socket on its side, everything gets handled well.

The problem I'm facing is that when a client connects and send a requests, if it does not close the socket on its side afterwards, I do not detect it and leave that socket "busy".

Is there any way to implement a system to detect if nothing is received on a socket after a certain time? In that way I could free that connection on the server side, leaving room for new clients.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could close the client connection when the client has not sent any data for a specific time.

For each client, you need to store the time when the last data was received.

Periodically, for example when `poll()` returns because the timeout expired, you need to check this time for all clients. When this time to too long ago, you can `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` and `close()` the connection. You need to determine what "too long ago" is.

If a client does not have any data to send but wants to leave the connection open, it could send a "ping" message periodically. The server could reply with a "pong" message. These are just small messages with no actual data. It depends on your client/server protocol whether you can implement this.

Comment: Yes, I just solved this way, keeping track of the time of the last received data, and updating it every time new data is received. After each timed out poll, I check for any expired timers and close the connection.